How to convert np.NaN to string in ndarray/list?
I have a simple Python code:
l2 =[4,np.nan, 5.1]
a2 = np.array(l2)

a3 = np.where(np.isnan(a2), '3.3', a2)
a3 = a3.astype(float)
print(a3)

a3 = np.where(np.isnan(a2), 'x', a2)
print(a3)

The code above produce two lines:
[4.  3.3 5.1]
['4.0' 'x' '5.1']

My question is how to convert np.NaN to string,  but without changes to other values.
There where was numbers should stay like number, but only there where is nan should be new string. Like that:
[4.0 'x' 5.1]

UPDATE:
If we can not mix data types in Numpy ndarray, I found new solution:
l2 =[4,np.nan, 5.1, np.nan, 3]
a2 = np.array(l2)

idxNan = (np.argwhere(np.isnan(l2)))
for idx in idxNan:
    l2[idx[0]] = 'x'
print(l2) 

Code above gave me right output:
[4, 'x', 5.1, 'x', 3]


Why are you trying to do this? (Yes, it matters.) NumPy arrays aren't designed to work like this. Having a better understanding of your underlying goal will let us suggest the most appropriate option for your actual situation.

Why would you want this? Numpy arrays are supposed to store data of the same type, not mixed. This is possible with object arrays, but then you might as well use a regular python list.

No problem I can convert ndarray to list. But how to do it in a list? I have ndarray because of np.where and np.isnan() functions.

Again though: why do you need this? Why do you need the numerical NaN converted to strings? And what is that result then going to get used for?

Is mixing forbidden? I need it for testing and studying.

Your l2 is a list, which can contain a mix of numbers and strings.  a2 is a numpy array, with float dtype.  It is possible make a numpy array with object dtype.  That will behave more like a list, containing references to objects stored elsewhere in memory.

@luki no, it's not forbidden, but it's bad practice and the wrong way to do whatever you're trying to do. The library is called numpy for a reason.

Thanks for the clarification. I am not an educated programmer. I don't know the limitations and I don't really feel what a programming language or library was created for

A list with a mix of int and float elements:
In [170]: l2 =[4,np.nan, 5.1]

A list comprehension to replace the nan element.  This could also be done inplace, but making a whole new list is quite idiomatic for python:
In [171]: ['x' if np.isnan(i) else i for i in l2]
Out[171]: [4, 'x', 5.1]

We can make an object dtype array from the list:
In [172]: arr = np.array(l2, dtype=object)    
In [173]: arr
Out[173]: array([4, nan, 5.1], dtype=object)

But math on such an array is hit-of-miss.  For example trying to test the whole for nan:
In [174]: np.isnan(arr)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[174], line 1
----> 1 np.isnan(arr)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

We can test the float array:
In [175]: arr = np.array(l2); arr
Out[175]: array([4. , nan, 5.1])
In [176]: np.isnan(arr)
Out[176]: array([False,  True, False])

where can work if we mix this mask and an object dtype array:
In [178]: np.where(np.isnan(arr),'x',arr.astype(object))
Out[178]: array([4.0, 'x', 5.1], dtype=object)

Probably not a lot of benefit over the list version.
